# Symfony2 get new value after UPDATE query

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

in my Symfony2.8 app I got the following controller:

```
public function changetariffAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
    $userid = $user->getId();
    $tariff = $user->getTariff();//tariff1 here

    $paymentForm = $this->createPaymentForm($user);
    $paymentForm->handleRequest($request);

    if($tariff != 'tariff2') {

        $query = $em->createQuery('UPDATE My\UserBundle\Entity\User u SET u.tariff = :tariff2 WHERE u.id = :userid');
        $query->setParameter('userid', $user->getId());
        $query->setParameter('tariff2', 'tariff2');
        $query = $query->getResult();//returns 1 here, tariff field in DB is set to tariff2 as expected

        $query = $em->createQuery('SELECT u FROM My\UserBundle\Entity\User u WHERE u.id = :userid');//getting once again user entity but it did not change
        $query->setParameter('userid', $user->getId());
        $user = $query->getResult();

        $tariff_upd = $user[0]->getTariff();//tariff1 here but I need tariff2! 
//Also I tried to persist and flush user entity here but it did not work
        return $this->render('MyBundle:Pages:tariffchangesuccess.html.twig', array(
        'user' => $user,
        'form' => $paymentForm->createView(),
        'tariff' => $tariff_upd //still tariff1 but I need tariff2 
    ));

    }
    return $this->render('MyBundle:Pages:tariffchangesuccess.html.twig', array(
        'user' => $user,
        'form' => $paymentForm->createView(),
        'tariff' => $tariff
        ));

}
```

My Controller works ok and all the values are updated in my DB as expected but new values (tariff2) are not rendered in my twig template. New values are rendered only when I update the page in my browser (hit F5), but this is not an expected behavior. Any ideas how to fix that? Thank you.

Comment: What is your DB engine ? You should use Doctrine methods when queries are not necessary. You really should not do DB queries in controller, but you should write a repository per entity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doctrine use something similar as cache and maybe your use of queries instead of natives methods short-circuit this system. Docrtine can handle your entities and know what to record and has been changed etc. But you have to use Doctrine functions or repositories for that, and not do it througt custom queries... The Doctrine way should be something like:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$userid = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser()->getId()
// Get object user from DB values
$user = $em->getRepository('My\UserBundle:User')->findOneById($userid );
// Update tarif in the user object
$user->setTariff('tariff2');
// Let Doctrine write in the DB. The persist() may not be necesary as Doctrine already manage this object, but it's a good practise.
$em->persist($user);
$em-> flush();
// Doctrine should already have update the $user object, but if you really really want to be sure, you can reload it:
$user = $em->getRepository('My\UserBundle:User')->findOneById($userid );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `refresh` method of the `EntityManager` in order to:

> Refreshes the persistent state of an entity from the database,
>   overriding any local changes that have not yet been persisted.

So add the refresh call, as example:

```
   $query = $em->createQuery('SELECT u FROM My\UserBundle\Entity\User u WHERE u.id = :userid');//getting once again user entity but it did not change
    $query->setParameter('userid', $user->getId());
    $user = $query->getResult();

    // Force refresh of the object:
    $em->refresh($user);

    $tariff_upd = $user[0]->getTariff();//tariff1 here but I need tariff2!
```

Hope this help